# New Item doesn't appear while creating a Sitecore Speak UI App using Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1, sitecore-rocks, sitecore-speak-ui

I'm trying to create a Sitecore App on Sitecore 7.1 with Speak UI framework using Sitecore Rocks. 
When I'm trying to add a new item nothing appears and it is blocked. 
I'm trying to follow this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2UZWcjqSPc) .

Please see attached picture. Do you have idea why is not working?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Templates under Recent are selected ?

Comment: In the attached picture it's selected but I try with All selected

Comment: Have you tried with SPEAK selected? Speak templates are placed outside of the "template" folder and All might be hardwired to /templates

Comment: Hi Jens,yes I tried with Speak Selected. Yes I saw that template folder in not inside regular templates folder.You say to move under regular templates folder?

Comment: Are you using Windows 8.1 - Rocks 1.0.1 is having a bit of trouble with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Windows 8.0. and Rocks 1.0.1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my project to Sitecore 7.1 Update 1 and everything works as expected. Strange but it's working now.